# Localization depending on iOS market

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

Is it any opportunity to have fixed list of localization depending on market that has been selected during app purchasing. Lets say if user downloads it from Germany market, only German localization can be used, if it is other market than English localization will be used. I need to manage this without checking GPS location.
Is it possible to do with Localizable.strings?

Comment: As far as I know, localizable.strings always relates to how a user actually configured his/her phone. I don't think you can restrict the localization like this. You probably could create two apps, one which is specific to the German store, one for the rest of the world. But this would mean that you'd have to use different app names. (as far as I know)

Comment: Yes, 2 apps this is good solution, I thought about this also.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? I can't think of a reason. It's a good thing to provide as many languages as you can (a user may have set their language to whatever they wish, no matter what market they use to download apps).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible unless you release two separate apps.

Furthermore, it is not recommended, because a decent share of iPhone users in Germany are foreigners, who are not necessarily fluent in German. They will get angry if your app's available localizations don't correspond to what the App Store says they are.